# Create graphviz dot file from SQLAlchemy models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, graphviz

Django has very nice extension for visualizing models: [graph_models](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoGraphviz). I wanted to use similar package but for SQLAlchemy. How can I turn SQLAlchemy models into dot graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ERAlchemy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ERAlchemy) can produce graphs from SQLAlchemy models.

Comment: In the meantime I found this package: https://github.com/fschulze/sqlalchemy_schemadisplay